# Extra space character for "visited" link in profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

When looking to "visited" field in profile page and cover it with mouse, I see underline like as if extra one space placed before "visited" word:

> [image: visited]

Related question in [ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3917/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) (look at **UPD** section).