# Letter case inconsistency in profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, wording

Each profile page even [your own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=profile) contains an information block on the right side like this:

> [image: info]

The last string begins with a lower case letter `v`. I'm pretty sure that here should be an upper case `V` for consistency with another predefined strings like: "Member for..." and "Last seen..."

Also don't forget about related bug report: [Extra space character for "visited" link in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286133/339911)